# Hive query in Shell Script

Tags: shell, count, hive, hql

I have an external hive table on top of a parquet file. 
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `parquet_test` LIKE avro_test STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'hdfs://myParquetFilesPath';
I want to get the count of table using shell script.

I tried with following command

```
myVar =$(hive -S -e " select count(*) from parquet_test;")
echo $myVar
```

Added -S to run hive in silent mode still I get whole map reduce log and count in the myVar variable. How to get only count.

I don't have access to any of the configuration file to enable or disable the level of logging. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a work around.
First flushed the query result into a file in HDFS then read answer from file.
The file only contains the result of the query.

```
(hive -S -e " INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/test/result/' 
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' select count(*) from parquet_test;")
```

Then reading the file into a variable

```
Count var=$(hdfs dfs -tail  /home/test/result/)
echo $var
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
myVar=$(eval "hive -S -e 'select count(*) from parquet_test;' ")

echo $myVar
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer? Just giving an answer provides a solution but prevents proper learning. :-)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17482841)

Comment: @Mayur No, it's not even a comment. It's just some code. But if it were elaborated a bit as da39a3ee suggested, it could be an answer. Even a good one ;-)